# Native Controller Support

Tags: 16.04

I'm new to Ubuntu, I tried to connect Logitech F710 controller to my computer and it worked, I didn't install anything. However, after playing for a while it started to have delay and act buggy. I searched for ways to solve this problem and I saw that there are some programs that make XInput controller work in Ubuntu but the controller is already connected and working, the problem is the delay, so should I install one of those anyway?

Also if not is there any fix for this?